# Spring Data JPA method execution time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Please see following (sudo) code:

```
public interface FooDAO extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
  // Query method1 - Database needs 10 mins to finish updating  
  void updateQueryMethod1()

  // Query method2
  void updateQueryMethod2()
}

@Transactional
public class FooService {
  
  FooDao fooDao;

  void fooServiceMethod() {
    
    fooDao.updateQueryMethod1();

    fooDao.updateQueryMethod2();
  }
}
```

Assume `updateQueryMethod1()` is a time consuming query in database. It takes 10 minutes to finish updating in the database.

My question is, in `fooServiceMethod()` method, will `updateQueryMethod2()` wait for `updateQueryMethod1()` to finish updating in database?

If `updateQueryMethod2()` does not wait for `updateQueryMethod1()` to finish updating in database, how to make `updateQueryMethod2()` wait for `updateQueryMethod1()` to finish its updating first?

Answer (score 0):

Methods or instructions are executed sequentialy and `updateQueryMethod2()` will be executed after `updateQueryMethod1()`. It also depends if your methods are excuted in a [synchronous](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-synchronous-callbacks-java/) or an asynchronous way. You have many ways to implement what you want:

1. [Observer Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm): `updateQueryMethod2()` will be executed as soon as `updateQueryMethod1()` notify `updateQueryMethod2()` that he finished is job
2. Put a `if` statement that will execute `updateQueryMethod2()` when `updateQueryMethod1()` execution result returns `true`

Comment: Hi Harry, thank you for your answer. I'm still confusing. For your 1st solution, are you referring thread method notify? For your 2nd solution, what if `updateQueryMethod1()` does not return anything?

Comment: @user5301398 I am referring to observer pattern. It implements a notification approach also

Answer (score 0):

Updates must acquire an exclusive lock over the TABLE they're modifying to avoid write-write conflicts,and since the first method(Transaction) acquired that ,the second method must wait until the exclusive lock is released so it can perform its update,so it must wait as long as the lock is retained by the other method(Transaction),that's why btw long running transactions are a detriment to a database performance because of this ,which is refered to as lock retention.